# firefox + flash disabled the ALT GR key : how to solve that?

Tags: flash, firefox, iframe

I am facing a big problem in firefox: the **ALT GR** key is disabled on some simple pages:
(try to type in an email)

This simple page DISABLES the **ALT GR** key

```
<html>
<body>
<iframe src="http://www.dialogoo.com/vdialogoo.php?id=2" width="100%" height="100%"></iframe>
</body>
```

but if you open 
http://www.dialogoo.com/vdialogoo.php?id=2

**ALT GR** is working !

This strange behaviour only happens on Firefox !
It seems Firefox + Iframe + Flash = disable ALT GR key !

Comment: The `@` key is disabled for me in Chrome without the iframe but works in Firefox

Comment: in what case you need access to Alt Gr key?

Comment: @Eugene on some keyboard layouts, Slovak/Czech for example, there is no @ symbol, only with Alt+64 or AltGr + V

Answer (score 0):

The only workaround I can think of is use JS to capture the ALT GR key down, then use External interface to pass it to the Flash and adjust your code accordingly. Pretty complicated, isn't it.